# Trace of an important class of operators

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, trace

In *Physics*, there exists an important class of operators of the form $e^{i A}$ (see equation ($14$) [in this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05748.pdf)). It is often of interest to calculate the trace $Tr[B e^{i A}]$ (such as equation ($18$) ). I want to know whether there is some standard way(s) to approach this problem in *Mathematics*?